# EC2 instance has no public DNS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-vpc

A guy I work with gave me the EC2 credentials to log onto his EC2 console. I was not the one who set it up. Some of the instances show a public dns name and others have a blank public DNS. I want to be able to connect to the instances that have a blank public DNS. I have not been able to figure out why these show up as blank.

Comment: Are the instances inside a VPC? Check if there is a value next to the VPC ID field in the instance description screen.

Comment: I have the same problem. My instances are inside a VPC, and on the Subnet, I have checked the public DNS to be available. Still I'm getting no public DNS names.

I can see that in my VPC configuration, it's saying `DNS hostnames: no`, but I cannot change that value and adding a new VPC doesn't give me the selection either.

Comment: I have different problem when setup [my-vpc](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38235022/4058484), The `DNS hostname: yes`, but it is only Private ID when the instance is started. I can only get the Public IP when an Elastic IP is used.

Comment: What helped me was a stop and start for the instance without the public IP/DNS (reboot didn't help). After instance was restarted, it got the public IP.

Answer (score 694):

I had the same problem an solved it. Have a look at the step-by-step instructions:

- Go to console.aws.amazon.com
- Go To **Services -> VPC**
- Open **Your VPCs**
- select **your VPC** connected to your EC2 and
- select Actions => Edit DNS Hostnames
  **---> Change DNS hostnames: to YES**

Comment: The section containing VPCs is now called Networking.  And to edit, you right-click on the VPC.

Comment: +1 you now also need to set your subnet to allow auto-assignment of public ip. Right click your subnet > modify auto-assign public ip > check the box

Comment: Even when I tried to add an Elastic Ip, it was not working until that option to change dns hostnames was set to yes.

Comment: How does doing this effect the instances that already have a Public DNS?

Comment: I thought this should be done in the subnet

VPC -> Subnets -> (Right Click on the) Subnet -> Modify Auto-Assign Public IP -> (Tick) Enable auto-assign public ip

Comment: Does this impact existing instances?

Comment: @ Jack BeNimble Yes. This will impact the existing instances in the VPC. Those instances will get the Public DNS.

Comment: @Vignesh But my existing instance still does not have a public DNS.

Comment: @Vignesh I did not get a public IP or DNS for existing instances. Stopping and restarting didn't change anything. The only thing that worked was to terminate and recreate the instance.

Comment: To reinforce @Yez prev comment, my problem was my existing EC2 instance still needed to be recreated for it to take effect after I made both config changes.
So as numerous other posts have properly documented both config settings:
VPC: Edit DNS hostnames = Enable 
Subnet: Auto-assign public IPv4 address = Yes
Then create AMI and, relaunch the instance.

Answer (score 65):

There is a actually a setting in the VPC called "DNS Hostnames". You can modify the VPC in which the EC2 instance exists, and change this to "Yes". That should do the trick.

I ran into this issue yesterday and tried the above answer from Manny, which did not work. The VPC setting, however, *did* work for me.

Ultimately I added an EIP and I use that to connect.

Comment: Is there a way to do this without modifying the VPC as a whole? I want public DNS for one node in a VPC but don't want it to apply to every other node with an elastic IP in that VPC.

Comment: I think you should be able to add an elastic IP for just that node, no?

Comment: Yeah, but it won't resolve internally without your suggestion in the answer :-)

Comment: using "DNS Hostnames" i am able to see Public DNS

Answer (score 44):

Sounds like the instance was launched in VPC and while doing so, the check-box for `Automatically assign a public IP address to your instances` was not checked. Hence the instance does not have a public IP

You can assign an Elastic IP to this instance and then log in using that IP.

Comment: I tried connecting using the public ip with putty. but it said "server refused our key". I converted the .pem file to .ppk file using puttygen

Comment: what user name are you using? which AMI is this ? what operating system is this ?

Comment: Is there a way to assign a public IP after the fact? I don't see a way to edit the Instance details settings.

Comment: @DavidBalažic, you can only assign an Elastic IP to a running instance.

Comment: @slayedbylucifer  What about a stopped instance?

Comment: @DavidBalažic, Same. for the lifecycle of an instance, you cannot attach pub IP. Pub IP can be attached only at the time of launch.

Comment: do you use the correct .pem file associated to the instance?
did you set a passphrase while you was creating the .ppk file? if so, don't do.

Comment: The only way to assign a public facing IP address _after_ the instance has been created is by assigning it an Elastic IP.

Answer (score 37):

In my case I found the answer from [slayedbylucifer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20945122/4058484) and others that point to the same are valid.
Even it is set that `DNS hostname: yes`, no Public IP is assigned on *[my-pvc](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38235022/4058484)* (only Privat IP).

> It is definitely that **Auto assign Public IP** has to be set `Enable`.
>   If it is not selected, then by default it sets to `Use subnet setting (Disable)`

[image: Assign Public IP]

Answer (score 24):

This is the tip provided to resolve the issue which does not work:

Tip - If your instance doesn't have a public DNS name, open the VPC console, select the VPC, and check the Summary tab. If either DNS resolution or DNS hostnames is no, click Edit and change the value to yes.

Assuming you have done this and you are still not getting a Public IP then go over to the subnet in question in the VPC admin screen and you will probably discover "Auto-Assign Public IP" is not set to yes.  Modify that setting then, and I know you don't want to here this, create a new instance in that subnet.  As far as I can tell you cannot modify this on the host, I tried and tried, just terminate it.

Answer (score 24):

1. Go to  AWS Console.
2. Go to  Services and select VPC
3. Click on vpc.
4. select the instance and click on Action.
5. Select  Edit DNS Host name click on yes.

At the end you will get your Public dns.

Comment: adding Public DNS to the VPC along with the assigned Elastic IP works. For some reason, the elastic IP can be pinged from the outside world through the Security Group but hitting a web app like Solr failed unless there's a public DNS assigned..

Answer (score 23):

For me problem was in subnet settings.

1. Open https://console.aws.amazon.com/vpc
2. Go to subnets in left menu
3. Choose your subnet
4. Modify auto-assigning IP settings to enable

Answer (score 22):

It is related to the VPC's feature called "DNS Hostnames". You can enable or disable it.  Go to the VPC, under the Actions menu select the "Edit DNS Hostnames" item and then choose "Yes". After doing so, the public DNS of the EC2 instances should be displayed.

Comment: Can I use my custom names? Cuz when I send emails from my instance, Gmail shows mailed by ec2..ip address...location..etc instead of my domain name

Comment: @mrid you need to associate your DNS with the generated DNS of the EC2. You can do it with AWS Route53 service, our your hosting/DNS manager.

Comment: Accidently I have deleted my default settings, and then I have to recreate Infrastructure, this works for me, Thanks :)

Answer (score 16):

Here I will summarize the most common issues that occur:

When you create a custom VPC, if you want aws resources such as ec2 instances to acquire public IP addresses so that the internet can communicate with them, then you first must ensure that the ec2 instance is associated with a public subnet of the custom VPC. This means that subnet has an internet gateway associated with it. Also, you need to ensure that the security group of the VPC associated with ec2 instance has rules allowing inbound traffic to the desired ports, such as ssh, http and https. BUT here are some common oversights that still occur:

1) You must ensure that DNS hostnames is enabled for the VPC

2) You must ensure the public subnet linked to the EC2 instance has its 'auto-assignment of public ip' flag enabled

3) If the instance is already created, then you might need to terminate it and create a new instance for the public IP and public DNS fields to be populated.

Comment: Once this public ip is visible in the launched instance, we can use this IP to connect the instance via putty SSH

Answer (score 12):

Just launch another instance (and also delete the one in question if it has no use) and make sure this time you check "Autoatically assign a public IP address to your instance".   If not then as slayedbylucifer suggested; assign an Elastic IP (EIP) to the instance and then log in using that IP.  Be careful though, if you are running the free AWS tier, an EIP will cost you money-- that's a whole 'nother topic..

Answer (score 7):

First of all, there can be two reasons for this:

1. You have created your own VPC and forgot to enable Public DNS.

To solve this :

i) Go to AWS VPC console and select the VPC you have created.

ii) Then click on Actions and then enable DNS Resolution.

```
            OR
```

2. You have not enabled public ip-assign option in EC2 configuration.

Here you cannot change the setting; so create an ami image and then recreate the instance from that.

Comment: These are two of many possible causes, certainly not the only two possibilities.

Answer (score 7):

After verifying VPC and Subnet settings, my EC2 instance still didn't have a public DNS. After a day of searching for a resolution, I finally figured it out.

I had to create a new Elastic IP address, then associate it to my instance.

From the EC2 Dashboard:

Go to **Elastic IPs** from the sidebar.

Click **Allocate new address**, then **Allocate**.

Go back to the EC2 Dashboard. Go to **Network Interfaces**.

Select the EC2 instance without a public DNS. Then **Actions - Associate Address**.

The **Address** field, select the new elastic IP address.

The **Associate to private IP address** field, select the private IP address with no public DNS.

Click **Associate Address**.

Your EC2 instance should now have a public DNS.

Comment: This was the answer for me. My VPC was already set up to enable public DNS.

Comment: Public DNS displayed, but still unable to connect through scp/putty. showing connection timeout!

Answer (score 4):

1. Go to VPC
2. Select your VPC
3. Click actions and choose Edit DNS hostnames
4. Tick Enable for DNS Hostnames
5. Click save changes

Answer (score 4):

##### The problem is that the DNS Host name in your VPC is dropped. You can easily enable it like this:

1. Go to your instance in the console, then click your **VPC ID**.
   [image]
2. In your VPC, select the `Edit DNS Host names` option
   [image: Select Edit DNS Host names]
3. Set it to **enabled** and save your changes.
   [image]
4. Now, in your EC2 instance window you can find the DNS:
   [image]

Comment: Did all this, but still did not work for me :(

Comment: You mean you can't see the public dns?

Answer (score 2):

The change to the DNS Hostnames setting can also be done using the AWS CLI:

```
aws ec2 modify-vpc-attribute --vpc-id $vpc_id --enable-dns-hostnames '{"Value": true}'
```

(Where $vpc_id is the ID of the VPC that your instance is attached to.)

As soon as the VPC is updated the instance will gain a public DNS.

Answer (score 2):

For those using CloudFormation, the key properties are **EnableDnsSupport** and **EnableDnsHostnames** which should be set to true

```
VPC: {
    Type: 'AWS::EC2::VPC',
    Properties: {
      CidrBlock: '10.0.0.0/16',
      EnableDnsSupport: true,
      EnableDnsHostnames: true,
      InstanceTenancy: 'default',
      Tags: [
        {
          Key: 'env',
          Value: 'dev'
        }]
    }
  }
```

Comment: Helpful answer, thanks. FYI the default for EnableDnsSupport is true so it's typically sufficient to indicate EnableDnsHostnames: true.

Answer (score 1):

If the instance is in VPC, make sure both "DNS resolution" and "DNS hostnames" is set to "yes". You can do this in the Aws console UI. HTH!

Answer (score 1):

Go to VPC console, select your VPC, and click ACTIONS menu, select Edit DNS Hostnames - select Yes. That should fix it.

Answer (score 1):

I tried to fix the 'no public DNS' 
once the EC2 was up and running, I couldnt add a public DNS

this is even after following the above steps making mods to the VPC or the Subnet

so, I had to make modifications to the subnet and the vpc, before starting another instance, and THEN start up a new instance.

the new instance had a public DNS.   That is how it worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

#### For those who are using Terraform.

To enable the DNS hostnames, use the following line in your `VPC` like this:

```
resource "aws_vpc" "app_vpc" 
{
   enable_dns_hostnames = true # Add this line

   cidr_block = var.vpc_cidr
   tags = { Name = "mostafa_vpc" }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to assign public ip address to your instance.
you can use NAT instances or NAT Gateway.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/VPC_Scenario2.html
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/vpc/latest/userguide/vpc-nat-comparison.html

Answer (score 0):

For the public IP / DNS first, you must have a running **EC2 Service** ( That can be Instance / Docker / Lightsail. for any of the services you will have two different IPs ( **Private & Public** ) also the security group available under the security Tab once you selected actively Instance.

**STEP-1**:

You can enable according to the port Usage like if you wanted to host a website using HTTP & HTTPS Ports

**EC2->Security Group -> Edit Inbound Rules -> Added or Remove required ports**.

like 80,443,22 etc and traffic source for the port ( if you want to make the port open for all select anywhere or if you want to open the application for the selected IPs- Enter IPV4/IPV6 manually.

once you are done with the above configuration, Create **Elastic IP** and attached it to your Running EC2 instance. Once you attached the IP with the instance your **Public IP will be the Elastic IP**

**STEP-2**:

AWS offers you one more service called **Route53**. Here you can create **Hosted Zones** and enter the domain name without www after creation, you will get the Name Server value for the hosted zone.

for more info about **Route53** https://aws.amazon.com/route53/