# AWS EC2 instance unable to ssh remote server

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, ssh, ubuntu-16.04

I have 2 EC2 Ubuntu instances: Instance-A and Instance-B. Both's ufw shows inactive and they are in the same subnet of a VPC. Both's security group allows all inbound and outbound traffic from anywhere. And they have identical ssh_config.

From command line of Instance-B, I can ssh to any of my SSH servers, either they are in the same VPC or non-AWS server.

However, from commaind line of Instance-A, I can only ssh to Instance-A and Instance-B using their private IP. I cannot ssh either (even Instance-A itself) using their public IP. Neither can I log in to any non-AWS server. The error is 'connection timeout'.

How can I make Instance-A' ssh client work?

**[added facts]**

1. In Instance-A, I can ping google.com, A's public IP, B's public IP
2. ssh client used to work well in Instance-A. I don't know what has changed.

Comment: Are they in a public subnet? Do both instances have a Private IP?

Comment: @JohnRotenstein yes they are both in public subnet and both have their own private IP

Comment: Maybe add or modify the security group associated with the ec2 instance so it can allow for external traffic on the appropriate port #. Make sure both ec2 instances have are in the same security group and make sure it allows for traffic

Comment: @JoeA security group was the first thing I checked and I think it is fine. Moreover, to completely isolate the cause of the issue I have changed both inbound and outbound rules to allow any connection from any IP

Comment: Oops, I meant do they both have a Public IP (not Private).

Comment: @JohnRotenstein yes they do

Comment: Maybe this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26706683/ec2-t2-micro-instance-has-no-public-dns

Comment: @JoeA My question is different as Instance-B does have a public IP and I can ssh to it from local PC. Besides, I can ping google.com and Instance-A's public IP. Anyway, Instance-B has been terminated and I will likely never find the answer.

Comment: Oh I'm sorry I misunderstood. I apologize for not being able to help you.

Comment: @JoeA Please don't be. Your comments and questions were highly appreciated!

Comment: @lonelyloner thank you for the kind words I appreciate it