# Unable to connect to amazon EC2 instance via PuTTY

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssh, amazon-ec2

I created a new instance of Amazon EC2 in Amazon Web Services (AWS) by [referring to the documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/EC2_GetStarted.html). I even added a SSH rule like this:

```
Port: 22  
Type: SSH  
Source: <My IP address>/32
```

I downloaded the `.pem` file, converted it into `.ppk` file by using `PuTTYGEN`. Then I added host name in PuTTY like this:

```
ec2-user@<public_DNS>
```

I selected `default settings`, added that .ppk file to PuTTY, logged in and I got this error:

[image: PuTTY error]

Even [trouble shooting link](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/TroubleshootingInstancesConnecting.html#TroubleshootingInstancesConnectionTimeout) didn't help me.
I'm also getting this error in system logs:
[image: img1]

How can I connect to my Amazon EC2 instance via PuTTY?

Comment: Is it Ubuntu Linux or some other distro?

Comment: Do you any response when you try telnet like this: telnet 52.27.219.7 22 ?

Comment: @helloV: it is amazon linux HMV(Fedora)

Comment: @VolkanPaksoy: I got this error: `Connecting To 52.27.219.7...Could not open connection to the host, on port 23: Connect failed`. I deleted my old instance and created new instance with the public ip `52.27.219.7`.

Comment: @AjayKulkarni: Port has to be 22, not 23. If still it doesn't work try allowing access from everywhere 0.0.0.0/32 temporarily. If it works then it has something to do with your IP. Make sure you still have the same external IP

Comment: I tried `telnet 54.68.184.49 22` where 22 is the port number. I got this error: `Connecting To 54.68.184.49...Could not open connection to the host, on port 22: Connect failed`. I set ip to `0.0.0.0/32`, and `telnet` didn't connect to the public ip. I'm updating the question, wait

Comment: `0.0.0.0/32` is *just* the  ip `0.0.0.0` - that's never going to be the source of any traffic.  `0.0.0.0/0` is *any* IP.  Better to put in *your* IP because if SSH is open to all IPs you _will_ have folks attempting to use it to access your system.

Answer (score 10):

Things to check when trying to connect to an Amazon EC2 instance:

- **Security Group:** Make sure the security group allows **inbound** access on the desired ports (eg 80, 22) for the appropriate IP address range (eg `0.0.0.0/0`). This solves the majority of problems.
- **Public IP Address:** Check that you're using the correct Public IP address for the instance. If the instance is stopped and started, it *might* receive a new Public IP address (depending on how it has been configured).
- **VPC Configuration:** Accessing an EC2 instance that is launched inside a Virtual Private Cloud (VPC) requires:

  - An **Internet Gateway**
  - A **routing table** connecting the subnet to the Internet Gateway
  - **NACLs** (Network ACLS) that permit through-traffic

If you are able to launch and connect to another instance in the same subnet, then the VPC configuration would appear to be correct.

The other thing to check would be the actual **configuration of the operating system** on the instance itself. Some software may be affecting the configuration so that the web server / ssh daemon is not working correctly. Of course, that is hard to determine without connecting to the instance.

If you are launching from a standard Amazon Linux AMI, `ssh` would work correctly anytime. The web server (port 80) would require installation and configuration of software on the instance, which is your responsibility to maintain.

Comment: Ajay, is your instance in a public subnet? If not, it would be unable to access the Internet, which could explain the failed cloud-init configuration and your inability to login. Look at the configuration of the subnet and ensure that it is routing through an Internet Gateway.

Comment: AWS Help Desk Answet: Network connectivity to an EC2 instance is not enabled by default. You need to make some configuration changes in your VPC in the AWS management console.                                  https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/ec2-linux-ssh-troubleshooting/

Answer (score 3):

Ajay,

Try this. Go to your VPC dashboard.  Click on Network ACLs - on the associated acl, update your Inbound Rules to allow SSH access on port22.

Answer (score 0):

Go to vpc attached to instance and then add entry to route table with 
0.0.0.0/0 - Destination
Internet Gateway of your VPC - As Target
Save It and try to connect it.

Answer (score 0):

Go to VPC --> Security Group --> Edit inbound rules --> make the ssh source ip (anywhere) then save it and try to login with your putty-client. finally go back to your security group inbound rules and change the source IP from (anywhere) to (my ip) or any custom IP do you want then save it.

note: I assume that you have successfully stored and converted your private key

Comment: What is "my ip"?  This might help but some details would be good.

Comment: @stdunbar In the INBOUND RULES 
Add a role as a SSH If you don't have yet and make the SOURCE from ANYWHERE then save it and try to log in from the CLI. Then go back and put your own IP address or an custom IP for security reasons. 
MyIP means your current IP.

Look at the screenshot  https://i.ibb.co/b7w4BBk/889.jpg

Answer (score 0):

1. Security Group - This must accept traffic from your IP address
   ex:

   Protocol - SSH, PORT-22, IPAddress - SOME IP ALLOW

   All Traffic On Any Port From 0.0.0.0/0 means from any IP Address ALLOW
2. Route Table - Make Sure you have outgoing traffic route enabled
   ex:
   Destination - 0.0.0.0
   target- internet gateway
3. Use or generate private key

Answer (score 0):

I struggled with this problem for ages after my EC2 instance suddenly started refusing a connection. I tried every answer on SO and Google but nothing helped!

The fix was to make sure that the Network ACL inbound rules were updated to match the rules on the security group.

I have no clue why it worked yesterday and stopped today, but this fixed it.